# "babel" package makes rendering of "forest" trees impossible

Tags: babel, forest

I am trying to recreate the example code from the [package documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/forest-doc.pdf/0) at page 29.

The package is called "forest" and is used to draw trees in LaTeX.

The example shows how to draw a tree, where every node is as wide as the sum of the widths of its children.

But the "babel" package interferes with "forest" and makes rendering impossible.

A minimum (not) working example:

```latex
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose, tmargin=2cm, bmargin=2cm, lmargin=2cm, rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\forestset{
    box/.style={
        draw, no edge, l=0, l sep=1.5ex, calign=first, anchor=base west,
        content format={\strut\forestoption{content}},
        if n children=0{}{
            after packing node={
                minimum width/.pgfmath={s("!l")+max_x("!l")-s("!1")-min_x("!1")},
                for children/.wrap pgfmath arg={s+={##1}}{0},
                typeset node
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{forest} for tree={box} [/
    [home[saso[Download][TeX]][alja][joe]]
    [usr[bin][share]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

In this form the line `minimum width/.pgfmath={s("!l")+max_x("!l")-s("!1")-min_x("!1")}` causes a `Missing number, treated as zero. \end{forest}` error.

But when I comment out the `\usepackage[german]{babel}` line, it works fine.

How can I use both packages in my document? Or is that not necessary, because I use the `ngerman` option for the `article` class?

Comment: use`\shorthandoff{"}` before \forestset. And use ngerman in the babel option. Is your file really latin9 encoded? Nowadays utf8 is the standard.

Comment: latin9 encoding is an old relict as I am using a preset and copying it around for years now. I need to update it in the near future. But thanks for your help

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`. Sec. 44 of the PGF/Ti*k*Z manual.